# How does an example of image data generator used on a vision transformer architechture look like?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I've built my own vision transformer for some classification task, and Instead of loading the image from directories and use them as raw numpy ndarray input, I want to use a directory structure such as data/train/class1 , class2 .... , data/test/class1 , class2.... and data/validation/class1 , class2... and then use the train test validation directories into ImageDataGenerator from tensorflow's Keras module. But every time at the time of running the training process the images are loaded with (None None None None) shape which is causing some functionality to raise errors.

Hence I wanted an example of the usage of ImageDataGenerator on transformer architechture.

Here's the code:

```
learning_rate = 0.0001
weight_decay = 0.0001
batch_size = 30
num_epochs = 100
image_size = 224  # We'll resize input images to this size
patch_size = 7  # Size of the patches to be extract from the input images
num_patches = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
projection_dim = 64
num_heads = 4
transformer_units = [
    projection_dim * 2,
    projection_dim,
]  # Size of the transformer layers
transformer_layers = 4
mlp_head_units = [1024, 512]
```

```
train_dat = train_gen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/working/data/train/' , 
                                          target_size = (224 , 224),  
                                          classes = classes,
                                          batch_size = 50,
                                          color_mode = 'rgb' ,
                                          class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_dat  = validation_gen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/working/data/validation/', 
                                                     target_size = (224 , 224) , 
                                                     classes = classes,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical', 
                                                     color_mode = 'rgb',
                                                     batch_size = 40)
```

```
def mlp(x, hidden_units, dropout_rate):
    for units in hidden_units:
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    return x
```

```
class Patches(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size):
        super(Patches , self).__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1 , patch_dims])
        
        return patches
```

```
def create_vit_classifier(input_shape):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
 
    # Create patches.
    patches = Patches(patch_size)(inputs)
    
    # Encode patches.
    encoded_patches = PatchEncoder(num_patches, projection_dim)(patches)

    # Create multiple layers of the Transformer block.
    for _ in range(transformer_layers):
        # Layer normalization 1.
        x1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
        
        # Create a multi-head attention layer.
        attention_output = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=projection_dim, dropout=0.1
        )(x1, x1)

        # Skip connection 1.
        x2 = tf.keras.layers.Add()([attention_output, encoded_patches])
        
        # Layer normalization 2.
        x3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x2)
        
        # MLP.
        x3 = mlp(x3, hidden_units=transformer_units, dropout_rate=0.1)
        
        # Skip connection 2.
        encoded_patches = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x3, x2])

    # Create a [batch_size, projection_dim] tensor.
    representation = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
    representation = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(representation)
    representation = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(representation)
    
    # Add MLP.
    features = mlp(representation, hidden_units=mlp_head_units, dropout_rate=0.5)
    
    # Classify outputs.
    logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(features)
    
    # Create the Keras model.
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
    
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

```
def run_experiment(model , train_dat , validation_dat):
    optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
        learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
            tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
        ],
    )
    
    history = model.fit(
        train_dat,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data = validation_dat,
        callbacks=[TerminateOnBaseline(model = model , baseline = 0.98)],
    )
    
    return history, model
```

Something like this in the run_experiment() method I wanna achieve but it throwing error in the "Patches" class due to images or the input shapes are coming as (None None None None).

Can you suggest something?

An example or the exact solution on this would be mostly preferred.